# typescript casting / assertion with a for loop

Tags: typescript, casting, type-assertion

I'm looping over data in an array and want to cast my looped item to an extended interface (it has an extra label field). What can I recast it? to a "PersonLabel"?

```
for (const person of people) {
    person.label = `${person.namespace}:${person.name}`;
    this.peopleList.push(person);
}
```

I tried approaches such as this (does not compile):

```
for (const person:PersonLabel of people) {
    person.label = `${person.namespace}:${person.name}`;
    this.peopleList.push(person);
}
```

and this (does not compile)

```
for (const person of people) {
    person = typeof PersonLabel;
    person.label = `${person.namespace}:${person.name}`;
    this.peopleList.push(person);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `<Type>` or `as Type`.

In your case this means:

```
person = <PersonLabel> person;
```

or the prefered way with `as`:

```
person = person as PersonLabel;
```

Remember to change `const person` to `let person` as you cannot reassign a `const`.

Or you can cast it already in the for loop like this:

```
for (const person of people as PersonLabel[]) { //<PersonLabel[] people should work as well...
  person.label = `${person.namespace}:${person.name}`;
  this.peopleList.push(person);
}
```

This assumes `PersonLabel` derives from the class `Person`. Otherwise you cannot cast the types (like you can't cast a `number` to `string`).

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
for (const person of people as PersonLabel[]) {
  person.label = `${person.namespace}:${person.name}`;
  this.peopleList.push(person);
}
```